# How to draw a (bezier) path with a fill color using GDI+?

Tags: c++, graphics, gdi+, svg

I am making a SVG renderer for Windows using the Windows API and GDI+. SVG allows setting the 'fill' and 'stroke' style attributes on a Path. I am having some difficulty with the implementation of the 'fill' attribute.

The following path represents a spiral:

```
    <svg:path style="fill:yellow;stroke:blue;stroke-width:2"
              d="M153 334
                C153 334 151 334 151 334
                C151 339 153 344 156 344
                C164 344 171 339 171 334
                C171 322 164 314 156 314
                C142 314 131 322 131 334
                C131 350 142 364 156 364
                C175 364 191 350 191 334
                C191 311 175 294 156 294
                C131 294 111 311 111 334
                C111 361 131 384 156 384
                C186 384 211 361 211 334
                C211 300 186 274 156 274" />
```

The fill color is yellow, and it should fill the entire shape, this is however what I get:

[image]

My GDI+ calls look like this:

```
Gdiplus::GraphicsPath bezierPath;
bezierPath.AddBeziers(&gdiplusPoints[0], gdiplusPoints.size());
g.FillPath(&solidBrush, &bezierPath);
g.DrawPath(&pen, &bezierPath);
```

Apparently the code is correct for drawing the shape, but not for filling it. Can anyone help me in figuring out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set the FillMode property of your GraphicsPath to FillMode::Winding, an alternate filling method that should suits your needs.